# How do relative imports work?

Tags: python, django

I have a directory structure like this

```
project/
        __init__.py
        greetings.py
        script.py
```

**greetings.py**

```
def hello():
    print('Hello')
```

**script.py**

```
from . import greetings

greetings.hello()
```

When I execute `python script.py` following error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import greetings
ImportError: cannot import name 'greetings'
```

If I just use `import greetings` in `script.py` everything works.
But why does the relative import give error?
And why does it work when I use `from . import models` in views while working in django.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow Module vs Package concept in python.

Here you created a package so you have to import package as:-

```
from project import greetings
```

Answer (score 0):

Here relative import will work as

```
from .greetings import *
```

OR

```
import greetings
```

`greetings` should be on same folder

Comment: That is because it is being executed relative to the directory where manage.py is present. Moreover, it also depends on how the path is set in manage.py